# Monitor processes with the same name, what am I doing wrong

Tags: c#, process, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I am making a test WinForm application, to try and monitor a processes with the same name.  But it is not working for some reason.

But my label on my form stays zero.

Form's global variables:

```
Thread checkProcess;
List<PerformanceCounter> pcs;
```

Button on click that starts the monitoring process

```
private void btnMonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Process> proc = new List<Process>();
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.ProcessName.IndexOf(txtProcessName.Text) > -1)
        {
            proc.Add(p);
        }
    }
    pcs = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
    int k = 0;
    foreach (Process p in proc)
    {
        pcs.Add(new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", k > 0 ?
            string.Format("{0}#{1}", p.ProcessName, k) : p.ProcessName, true));
        lstbxPC.Items.Add(k > 0 ?
            string.Format("{0}#{1}", p.ProcessName, k) : p.ProcessName);
        k++;
    }
    checkProcess = new Thread(CheckProcess);
    checkProcess.Start();
}
```

The method (starts in its own thread) that monitors and updates the label:

```
private void CheckProcess()
{
    int temp = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        temp = 0;
        foreach (PerformanceCounter pc in pcs)
        {
            if (temp < pc.NextValue())
            {
                temp = (int)pc.NextValue();
            }

        }
        // Set the label in a ThreadSafe way. This does work
        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(lblCPU, "Text", Convert.ToString(temp) + "%");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do *not* call pc.NextValue() twice in a row, only call it once per second.

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that! Most likely the reason for it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
    private void btnMonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var proc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName.IndexOf(this.txtProcessName.Text) > -1);
        var k = 1;
        var appendSuffix = proc.Count() > 1;

        this.pcs = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
        foreach (var p in proc)
        {
            this.pcs.Add(new PerformanceCounter(
                "Process",
                "% Processor Time",
                appendSuffix ? string.Format("{0}#{1}", p.ProcessName, k) : p.ProcessName,
                true));
            this.lstbxPC.Items.Add(appendSuffix ? string.Format("{0}#{1}", p.ProcessName, k) : p.ProcessName);
            k++;
        }

        this.checkProcess = new Thread(this.CheckProcess);
        this.checkProcess.Start();
    }

    private void CheckProcess()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var temp = 0;

            foreach (var pc in this.pcs)
            {
                var nextValue = pc.NextValue();

                if (temp < nextValue)
                {
                    temp = (int)nextValue;
                }
            }

            // Set the label in a ThreadSafe way. This does work.
            SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(lblCPU, "Text", Convert.ToString(temp) + "%");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like how you fetched the processes.  Where can I learn more how to use code like that?

Comment: That is known as LINQ (Language INtegrated Query). Here's a page with some code samples you can use to start learning it: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to check :

- Does your `pcs` have items ? (Debug)
- What is the text in `txtProcessName` ? (pattern is `{process name without exe}#{nb}`, like devenv#1, devenv#2, ...}
- Can you read Performance Counters ? (check security)
- Because you are casting NextValue() to int, you will not see any changes < 1%

You should also change your code, because if a process stops, you will get an exception (instance is missing in the counter category).

Comment: You are right, I should handle, if a process stops. A try catch, in the `private void CheckProcess()` method. When caught, just delete the `PerformanceCounter`, which the process stops, from the list. Should do the trick.